# Quality loss of animation when exporting to After effects

Tags: rendering, export, transparency

I need to export animation from blender with transparent background to then use it in After Effects.

The problem is when I import rendered animation in AE, lightsaber looks way worse than it should. How can I fix this?

This is how it should look.

[image]

This is how it actually looks in After Effects

[image]

My export settings in blender

[image]

How can I fix this?

[UPD-13 May 21] I've tried to render animation as image sequence and it still looks the same, saber doesn't have red bloom around the edges.

Answer (score 0):

**FIXED**

[image]

1. Enable bloom in passes. Go to view layer properties -> Passes -> Effects -> Bloom
2. In compositor tab, add "Mix" node and change it to "Add" and connect nodes accordingly as shown on screenshot above.

*Hope this helps*